# LINQ query to match multiple words

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to solve this problem all day, and haven't found a solution that truly works. When I search for some data, I want to filter out the data based on multiple words.

My input value is split up by using the standard .Split-function.

```
string[] searchstrings = MessageResult.Split(' ');
```

I've made a query (which obviously doesn't work properly) that tries to filter out all the entries that matches every string in searchstrings.

```
                    var suggestions = (from a in query
                               from w in searchstrings
                               where a.Message.ToLower().Contains(w.ToLower())
                               select a).Distinct();
```

query is my variable which has all the data. How can I make this query to actually only match out entries that includes every string in searchstrings?

Comment: To clarify, you want the strings from query that contain every split string, that is to say, **every** string in searchString must be in the resulting strings?

Comment: if the question of @Breland is true, does that would work changing .Contains to .All
I would like to see the query generated by that expression

Comment: what should be your final output ?

Comment: Just to mention, though both answer below are where I'd take this, if you're going looking for only a subset of keywords, you may have to involve a predicate builder. This will allow you to build dynamic expressions and do some slightly more complex queries.

Comment: @Breland, that is correct. The final output should only retrieve strings from query that contains all the strings in searchstrings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think code below should solve your problem. It checks if all words in searchstring are in a query (a).

```
var suggestions = (from a in query
                   where searchstrings.All(word => a.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))
                   select a);
```

Answer (score 19):

```
var query = new string[]
{
    "abc foo bar xyz john doe",
    "abc foo bar xyz doe",
    "hello world",
    "abc foo bar john doe",
};

var searchstrings = new string[]
{
    "abc",
    "foo",
    "john",
    "xyz",
};

searchstrings = searchstrings.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();

var results = query.Select(x => x.ToLower())
                   .Where(x => searchstrings.All(y => x.Contains(y)));
```

Note:
`ToLower()` is performed outside the `Where` clause, to save a lot of calls to that method.